# Buick Regal tail lights inop. And chiming

Tags: electrical, lights, buick

I have a 2000 Buick Regal with several symptoms. 
The fuse for the tail lights keeps burning out. 
The dashboard dimmer doesn’t work, even with the headlights on. 
The automatic lights don’t work
When the key is off, and headlights off, the car chimes as if the headlights are left on.

Brake lights and turn signals work.

Comment: This sounds like an issue with the Body Control Module (BCM). I believe it controls all of the things you mention here.

Comment: Which fuse? There are two. Does the fuse blow right away or over time? What kind of output voltage do you see at the dimmer?